# I am reading Acts 3:17-23 (NIV) and I am trying to understand why it seems like the writer is discussing Jesus, but also a Messiah other than Jesus

Tags: acts, prophecy, messiah

> <sup>**17**</sup> “Now, fellow Israelites, I know that you acted in ignorance, as did your leaders. <sup>**18**</sup> But this is how God fulfilled what he had foretold through all the prophets, saying that his Messiah would suffer. (*referring to Jesus*) <sup>**19**</sup> Repent, then, and turn to God, so that your sins may be wiped out, that times of refreshing may come from the Lord, <sup>**20**</sup> and that "he" (*God*) may send the **Messiah,** (*not Jesus, as He has already come*) who has been appointed for you—even Jesus. <sup>**21**</sup> Heaven must receive **him** (*this other Messiah*) until the time comes for God to restore everything, as he promised long ago through his holy prophets. <sup>**22**</sup> For Moses said, ‘The Lord your God will raise up for you a prophet like me from among your own people; you must listen to everything he tells you. <sup>**23**</sup> Anyone who does not listen to him will be completely cut off from their people.’
>
> <sup>[bold and italics mine]</sup>

Comment: quote and format the text properly as others do with the bible version name. Also using a link like stepbible.org will be great.

Comment: the verse is referring to Jesus directly, he is the direct object along with Christ, in v20 which is your focus. You are just misunderstanding it. Also see NET footnotes which are helpful. It is referring to the second coming of Christ from heaven. https://www.stepbible.org/?q=version=ESV|version=NETfull|version=NIV|version=SBLG|reference=Acts.3.20&options=GNVUVH&display=INTERLEAVED

Comment: This all refers to Jesus Christ/Messiah and His return the second time.  Heb 10:24-26.

Comment: The Messiah was sent (first) so that he might suffer (second). But he will not appear (spiritually to the inward soul) unless there is repentance first.

Comment: Acts 3:20 explicitly says that the Messiah is Jesus.  Otherwise, I am at a complete loss to understand this question.

Answer (score 2):

As I read these verses, "heaven must receive" in v21 refers to the fact that Jesus has ascended. Then the plea that God "send him" in v20 is for Jesus to come *back*, which was the expectation of the New Testament church (and the present-day church, of course). To quote just one reference among many, Paul says about the Corinthians "You wait for the revealing of our Lord Jesus Christ" (1 Corinthians ch1 v7, RSV). "Revealing" is a slightly different image for the Return, implying that Jesus has not really gone anywhere but remains "hidden".

"When the time comes to restore everything" is translated in the RSV as "the time for establishing [i.e. fulfilling] all that God spoke through the mouths of his holy prophets". As an example of which, v22 identifies Jesus as the fulfilment of the promise made by Moses.